# Random 'mark' generated on x-axis in Scatter Plot using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I generated the following Scatter Plot 
[image]

With this code

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=12.092605737472649cm,y=374.6606503225678cm]
    \draw[->,color=black] (0.,0.) -- (0.85,0);
    \foreach \x in {,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8}
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
    \draw[->,color=black] (0.,0.) -- (0.,0.02669082005647084);
    \foreach \y in {0.005,0.01,0.015,0.02,0.025}
    \draw[shift={(0,\y)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
    \draw[color=black] (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};
    \clip(0.,0.) rectangle (0.8269516278871089,0.02669082005647084);
    \begin{scriptsize}
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.,0.) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.0326,0.00599337793538) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.066567,0.00800334092061) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.099533,0.0118183240821) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.1335,0.0162894171978) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.166467,0.0199695510686) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.199433,0.0224502399865) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.2334,0.0232532463933) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.266367,0.0234484998458) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.300333,0.0235156791863) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.3333,0.0236558243653) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.366267,0.0240320568046) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.400233,0.0237211598547) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.4332,0.0228133071563) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.467167,0.022779717486) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.500133,0.0226828018266) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.5331,0.0224762107547) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.567067,0.0230861344422) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.600033,0.0239829235302) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.634,0.0237828910273) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.666967,0.0230542213422) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.699933,0.023526158748) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.7339,0.0235532932594) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.766867,0.0228133071554) circle (1.5pt);
    \end{scriptsize}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But as you can see in the bottom right corner there's a random mark going further than the line, and I can't for the life of me see what in the code is forcing that mark.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

In general with drawing of function plots in normal or logaritmic scaling you will have less problems, more clear and compact code with smaller probability of coding errors if you will use **pgfplots** package. It is based on TikZ and is designed for user-friendly interfaces for drawing line, scatter, bar, mesh and similar plots. By it your MWE can be as follows:

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 

\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.266,0.266,0.266}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
width=85mm, height=50mm,
  scaled y ticks = false,% xmin = 0.00,  ymin = 0.0,
yticklabel style = {/pgf/number format/fixed,
                     /pgf/number format/precision=3},
tick label style = {font=\footnotesize},
scale only axis,
xmax = 0.85,ymax = 0.028,
      axis lines = left,
      xlabel = {$x$},
      ylabel = {$y$}
            ]
\addplot[only marks,mark size=1.5pt] coordinates {
    (0.0,0.0)
    (0.0326,0.00599337793538)
    (0.066567,0.00800334092061)
    (0.099533,0.0118183240821)
    (0.1335,0.0162894171978)
    (0.166467,0.0199695510686)
    (0.199433,0.0224502399865)
    (0.2334,0.0232532463933)
    (0.266367,0.0234484998458)
    (0.300333,0.0235156791863)
    (0.3333,0.0236558243653)
    (0.366267,0.0240320568046)
    (0.400233,0.0237211598547)
    (0.4332,0.0228133071563)
    (0.467167,0.022779717486)
    (0.500133,0.0226828018266)
    (0.5331,0.0224762107547)
    (0.567067,0.0230861344422)
    (0.600033,0.0239829235302)
    (0.634,0.0237828910273)
    (0.666967,0.0230542213422)
    (0.699933,0.023526158748)
    (0.7339,0.0235532932594)
    (0.766867,0.0228133071554)
    };
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

By the way, in drawing of diagrams has no sense to exaggerate
 in coordinate precision. In most cases the precision of 1% is more than adequate.

Comment: Be fair - **pgfplots** is not good for drawing diagrams *generally*. I assume you mean for diagrams of plots etc. I guess that the TikZ facilities would be another option here, although **pgfplots** seems more popular. (Maybe it is more powerful?)

Comment: Be honest, I wasn't very careful in selection of term (on on side) and the meaning is consequently lost by translation (on another side) :-(. According to wikipedia, the terms for description of sort of drawings, where pgfplots has advantages and was designed for are tree diagrams, histograms, bar graphs, function graph, scatter plots (ordered as mention in wikipedia). I will try to rephrase the first sentence in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As given, your code cannot be compiled as a library is wanting. Once this deficit is made good, the MWE can be reduced to this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% deprecated - consider arrows.meta instead
\begin{document}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round, line join=round, >=triangle 45, x=12.092605737472649cm, y=374.6606503225678cm]
  \draw[->,color=black] (0.,0.) -- (0.85,0);
      \foreach \x in {,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8}
      \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: stray mark]

The stray mark is caused by a stray comma in the set of values for the loop. Corrected code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% deprecated - consider arrows.meta instead
\begin{document}
\definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round, line join=round, >=triangle 45, x=12.092605737472649cm, y=374.6606503225678cm]
  \draw[->,color=black] (0.,0.) -- (0.85,0);
      \foreach \x in {0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8}
      \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: correct output]